# how to check whether 2 strings are rotations to each other ?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, comparison, rotation

Given 2 strings, design a function that can check whether they are rotations to each other without making any changes on them ? The return value is boolean.

e.g  ABCD, ABDC, they are not rotations. return false

ABCD, CDAB or DABC are rotations. return true.

My solution:

shift one of them to right or left one position  and then compare them at each iteration. 
If they are not equal at all iterations, return false. Otherwise, return true.

It is O(n). Are there other more efficient solutions ? 
What if the contents of them cannot be changed ?

thanks

Comment: I think you need to review your O() notation. That is not O(n).

Comment: First, as @Chriszuma points out, your algorithm is not O(n).  Second, you cannot possibly do better than O(n) because that is required just to _examine_ the strings.  (And obviously you cannot solve this problem without examining the strings.)  I seriously doubt you can even achieve O(n) for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

1. Concatenate the given string with the given string.
2. Search for the target string in the concatenated string.

Example:

```
Given = CDAB

After step 1, Concatenated = CDABCDAB

After step 2, Success CDABCDAB
                        ^^^^
```

Comment: Don't you mean "concatenate the given string with itself"?

Comment: *"without making any changes on them"*

Comment: @Branko -- Then make a copy first.

Comment: Step 0: Make sure strings are same size.

Comment: @ArunSaha This is incorrect: what if `Given = ABCD` and you are searching for `ABCDABCD`?

Comment: @Branko: Good point, lets see. To me, "ABCD" is a sub-string of "ABCDABCD"

Comment: @ArunSaha "ABCDABCD" is a substring of "ABCD" + "ABCD" but "ABCDABCD" is not a rotation of "ABCD". For a rotation, you'd also need to ensure that string sizes match, but OP did not indicate if string size is available as a constant-time operation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley This may not be spelled-out in the question, but I feel this is against the *spirit* of the question - I think it should be read more as "in place" than "leave originals unchanged". Also, there is a very practical issue of performance when working with big strings (or large number of small strings).

Comment: @user1002288: but it takes O(*n*) working memory, which may or may not be what the OP wanted. +1 though.

Comment: @user1002288 Your original solution is NOT O(n) btw - its O(n^2). As has already been mentioned, you need to make one pass of the strings come what may (which by definition is O(n)).

Comment: For efficient substring matching algorithm, one very good algorighm is KMP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: @ArunSaha KMP is still O(n) for each comparison in your algorithm, so finally it is O(n^2), right ? we need to compare O(n) for each char in the target string.

Comment: I think it is enough to run KMP *once* as: `KMP( needle = "ABCD", haystack = "CDABCDAB" )`. Then there is no "each comparison" and the whole algorithm runs in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the strings, just take the first character of string1 and compare it to each character of string2. When you get a match, compare the second char of string1 to the next char of string2, and so on.

Pseudocode:

```
len = strlen(string1);
len2 = strlen(string2);
if( len != len2 )
  printf("Nope.");

for( int i2=0; i2 < len; i2++ ) {
  for( int i1=0; i1<len; i1++ ) {
    if( string1[i1] != string2[(i2+i1)%len] )
      break;
  }
  if( i1 == len ) {
    print("Yup.");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: it is O(n^2) worse than O(n).

Comment: You could also adapt Boyer-Moore or Knuth-Morris-Pratt to search for s1 in the "wrapped" s2.  I suspect for long strings this would be extremely fast in practice, even if the worst case is still O(n^2)

Comment: Man... Boyer, Moore, Knuth, Morris, and Pratt were pretty smart dudes.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than shifting one of them, it might be more efficient to use two index variables. Start one at 0 each time and the other at each of the possible positions (0 to N-1) and increment it [mod N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

A simple one would be:

```
(s1+s1).find(s2) != string::npos && s1.size() == s2.size();
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `s1="a"`, `s2="aa"` would give you a match.

Comment: Sure. The problem with this is that these may not necessarily be `std::string`s (elements may not even be characters in a general case) and `size()` may not be available in constant-time. Also, you are creating a new string - the spirit of the question seems to be "in place" (not just "not modifying original strings").

Comment: @Branko, the tags are specifically c++ and string. I'm going with std::string. As far as O(1) for size() goes; The standard specifies a "should" for O(1), since we were using flint and tinder, so I'll make an educated guess most implementation does just that. If creating the extra string is too expensive for the OP than this is not the way to go.

Comment: The description of `string` tag says: *"A String is a sequence of zero or more characters. It is commonly used to represent text."*. This may be `char*` (which of course does not have a constant-time `size()`). And I managed to misread `comparison` tag as `competition` so I assumed the performance is an absolute must. I tend to be overzealous this way sometimes, sorry ;)

Comment: @Branko Indeed, a competition-tag would be a whole other beast. No worries mate.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe, your solution looks simple but it is still O(n) due to the find().

Comment: @user100 This is impossible to achieve under O(N), all elements needs to be inspected.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe, the find() may be O(n^2), because for each substring with length n in s1+s2, each char inside the substring should be compared with each char of the target string s2. right ?

Comment: @user1002288 There are quite a few string matching algorithms that does better than O(N²). SO even has a tag for string-matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstring>
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;
  void CompareString(string, string, int);
  int ComputeStringLength(string str);
  int main()
  {
   string str = ""; string str1 = ""; int len = 0, len1 = 0;
   cout << "\nenter string ";
   cin >> str;
   cout << "\nenter string 2 to compare:-  ";
   cin >> str1;

   len = ComputeStringLength(str);
   len1 = ComputeStringLength(str1);
   if (len == len1)
    CompareString(str, str1, len);
   else
    cout << "rotation not possible";
   getchar();
   return 0;
  }

  int ComputeStringLength(string str)
  {
   int len = 0;
   for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
    len++;
   }
   return len;
  }


  void  CompareString(string str, string str1, int n)
  {
   int index = 0, flag = 0, curr_index = 0, count1 = 0, flagj = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {
    for (int j = flagj; j<n; j++)
    {
     if (str[i] == str1[j])
     {
      index = j;
      flagj =j;
      count1++;
      flag++;
      if (flag == 1)
      {
       curr_index = index;
      }
      break;
     }

    }
   }
   int temp = count1;
   if (count1 != n)
   {
    if (curr_index>=0)
    {
     int k = 0;
     for (int i = n - 1; i>n - curr_index - 1; i--)
     {
      if (str[i] == str1[k])
      {
       temp++;
       k++;
      }

     }
    }
    if (temp == n)
    {
     cout << "\n\nstring is same after rotation";
    }
    else
    {
     cout << "\n\nstring is not same after rotation";
    }
   }
   else
   {
    cout << "\n\nstring is same after rotation";
   }

  }
```

https://dsconceptuals.blogspot.in/2016/10/a-program-to-check-if-strings-are.html